# Is it acceptable to put std::promise-s into a container to be set by the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, design-patterns, std-future

There is a thread which is responsible for executing a certain task and acquire the result. To execute the task certain data is needed and it is being produced by multiple `clients` and the result must be returned to them. The solution that I am thinking about is to put the `data` into a thread safe execution queue along with a `std::promise` which its `future` is retrieved in the `client` code and will be kept to later get the result out of it. The worker thread then fetches the data and the `std::promise`, execute the task and set the `std::promise`'s value. The `client` which is now waiting on the `std::future` gets its corresponding result.
The implementation works technically but my question is that

- Is there a **better way** to get the same outcome?
- Is there any **issue** or **performance** penalty with this approach?
- What are the **best paractises** for this kind of problem?

The code below shows the method described:

```
std::condition_variable_any workerCv;
std::mutex workerMutex;
SomeThreadSafeQueue<std::pair<int, std::promise<int>>> threadSafeQueue;

int process(int data) {
  // Create the promise
  std::promise<int> promise;
  // Get the future and keep it
  auto future = promise.get_future();
  // Move the promise along with the data into the thread safe queue
  threadSafeQueue.emplace({ data, std::move(promise) });
  // Notify the worker about the new data
  workerCv.notify_one();
  // Get the result
  return future.get();
}

void worker(std::stop_token stopToken) {
  while (!stopToken.stop_requested()) {
    
    // Construct the unique lock needed for condition variable
    std::unique_lock lock(workerMutex);
    
    // Wait for notification
    workerCv.wait(lock, stopToken, []() {return !threadSafeQueue.empty(); });
    // unlock since we don't need the lock for anything other than the condition variable
    lock.unlock();

    // Check for stop condition
    if (stopToken.stop_requested()) {
      break;
    }
    // Fetch the data and promise from the queue. This specific queue front method
    // moves the item out of the queue
    auto&& [data, promise] = threadSafeQueue.front();
    try {
      // Use the data to run some operation and set the result in the corresponding promise
      promise.set_value(someOperation(data));
    }
    catch (...) {
      // Set any possible exception into the promise
      promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
    }
  }
}

void client(int start, int end) {
  for (int data = start; data < end; ++data) {
   
    try {
      // Call the process function that puts the data into the
      // thread safe queue and gets the result when it is ready
      // then use it
      useTheResult(process(data));
    }
    catch (const std::exception& exception) {
      // Handle the exception
      // Not thread safe but ok for demo
      std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  // Stop source for the worker thread
  std::stop_source stopSource;
  // Invoke the worker thread
  std::jthread workerThread(worker, stopSource.get_token());
  // Invoke the clients
  std::thread client1(client, 0, 10);
  std::thread client2(client, 10, 20);
  // Join the clients
  client1.join();
  client2.join();
  // Signal the worker thread to stop
  stopSource.request_stop();
  workerCv.notify_one();
}
```

As mentioned before the solution works as expected but I have never seen the same approach for using `std::promise` and `std::future` so I assume that there is some issue with it?